# Handling Filepaths in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am using stings to hold filepaths in python and I want to replace the single backslash with a double backslash for use in cmd but I have a problem where due to the backslash it is changing a letter into a special characters. For example:

```
string="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
print(sting)
```

outputs:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\x0cirefox.exe"
```

when I want it to output

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

This problem continues when I want to replace the "\" with a "\\" using

```
string.replace("\\","\\\\")
```

Instead of it outputing:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
```

It outputs:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\xocirefox.exe"
```

Comment: [Oblig. xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1638/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raw strings:

```
>>> string=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
>>>print(string)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

>>> print(string.replace('\\','\\\\'))
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw strings to simply ignore the backslash.

```
>>> string=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
>>> print(string)
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

You can find out more about this in the [Python documentation for lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: Thanks this has fixed my problem i will accept this answer when it allows me to.

Comment: how can you convert a variable holding a string into a raw string?

Comment: The "raw string" is just a syntax feature for typing string _literals_ in the source code.  At Python object level there's no difference.

Comment: the probelm i have is that i need to take the string in the question and use it in the cmd using subprocess but it needs to be used in a variable which will can only be assinged as a normal string but if i try to replace the slashes i encounter the problem above so i need a way to tell python the variable should be a raw string when im calling it.

Comment: So there's another problem... Perhaps you could write another question describing the exact situation.